# Analytic formulae for the gravitational field of a cosmic string/domain wall?

Tags: gravity, cosmic-string, domain-walls

Is there any analytical approximate (newtonian, postnewtonian) formulae for the gravitational field/potential of cosmic strings/domain walls?

Comment: The *exact* metric of a straight infinitely-thin string is [known](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Cosmic_strings#Bulk_Properties).